# как отпозиционировать такое?как вообще перенести флекс элементы на новую строку?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите пожалуйста.как правильно отпозиционировать данную систему? можно использовать гриды и флексы.
чтобы все было честно,прилагаю свою верстку

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container2" style="width: 70%;">
    <div style="background-color:  #cccccc;
      width: 770px;
      height: 430px;
      margin: 10px;">
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:  #cccc00;
      width: 370px;
      height: 250px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: right;">
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:  #cc00cc;
      width: 370px;
      height: 530px;
      margin: 10px;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container3" style="width: 30%;">
    <div style="background-color:  #00cccc;
      width: 370px;
      height: 710px;
      margin: 10px;
      float: right;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: используйте masonry плагин и не мучайтесь

Comment: Интересно, а где здесь вообще `flex` элементы?

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы флекс элементы перенести в новую строку нужно задать им (или лучше добавить их все в один контейнер) и задать ему свойство `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Вот пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  padding: .25em;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.wrap div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
.box {
  height: 80px;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.tall {
  flex: 0 0 65%;
  height: 160px;
}
.col {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.mini {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box tall"></div>
  <div class="box col">
    <div class="mini"></div>
    <div class="mini"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

На flex это будет примерно вот так. Для преноса используйте `flex-wrap` и `flex-basis` для управления размерами.

```css
.bg-grey {
  background: #eaeaea;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.main {
  width: 67%;
}
.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.banners {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}

.banners__block--small {
  height: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 0.5rem);
}
.banners__block--small:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.banners__block--big {
  
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="slider bg-grey">
    
    </div>
    <div class="banners">
      <div class="banners__block banners__block--small bg-grey">
      
      </div>
      <div class="banners__block banners__block--small bg-grey">
      
      </div>
      <div class="banners__block banners__block--big bg-grey">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="sidebar bg-grey">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не поможешь кое с чем?как такое же на гридах сделать?

Comment: @ChelokovAmyr С гридами не смогу помочь.